# Tensorflow Model Garden Tutorial with different models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden

I’m trying to follow this colab notebook. Google Colab

I want to try different models. I try to change the model line like below:
exp_config = exp_factory.get_exp_config(‘coco_spinenet49_mobile_tpu’)
But it does not work.
I get model names from following link: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/MODEL_GARDEN.md

But I also wonder that can I use model zoo? : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md

Thank you for your interest.

Trying new model in tutorial.

Comment: Can you report the error and part of the code you are using in your question?

Answer (score -1):

Solution is using model from this link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfm/core/exp_factory/get_exp_config

```
exp_factory.get_exp_config('MODEL NAME FROM LINK')
```

Comment: ??????????????????????????